# How to debug React SSR bundle in WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, server-side-rendering

I have a largish React app that I'm using SSR (server-side rendering) to initially render.  In a separate client project, Webpack is used to make a minified bundle for SSR to use, with `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` turned on.  The bundle is then copied into the server build to be run at each request.

Is there any way configure WebStorm so that I can debug into the client bundle as it's being rendered on the server?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to set breakpoints.

Comment: could you use [`--debug`](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27) in your node script? it will allow you to debug with chrome dev tools but maybe you can configure webstorm somehow too with it.

Comment: @Tomasz Webpack uses node debugging already; --debug is baked in.  I suspect that Webpack won't chase source-map source references to files outside of the project unless I tell it to somehow - but that's just a guess.